# Automatically adding category filter based on search string

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, search

Like ebay and amazon, i want to implement something on my site wherby if someone searches e.g red dresses then the category "Women's dresses" is only searched within.

As seen as below, a generic ebay search for iphone only searches withn iphone and filters it specifically and automatically.

https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_osacat=0&_odkw=hats&_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xiphone.TRS0&_nkw=iphone&_sacat=0

Comment: So, if I type in `dresses` in search, if a category or term is named `dresses`, you want to redirect from search to that archive? Keep in mind that WooCommerce specific questions are offtopic here, 3rd party plugin support is not in the scope of this stack, your Q will need to be phrased in general WP terms rather than WooCommerce specific